# jquery length error when trying to find json file through Ajax within .Net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

I have been receiving this error within jquery:

```
Unhandled exception at line 422, column 4 in http://localhost:59307/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference occurred
```

This is displayed within this jquery method:

```
grep: function( elems, callback, invert ) {
    var callbackInverse,
        matches = [],
        i = 0,
        length = elems.length,
        callbackExpect = !invert;

    // Go through the array, only saving the items
    // that pass the validator function
    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
        callbackInverse = !callback( elems[ i ], i );
        if ( callbackInverse !== callbackExpect ) {
            matches.push( elems[ i ] );
        }
    }

    return matches;
},
```

Specifically the line:

```
length = elems.length
```

This is being caused by this Ajax statement which is trying to find a json file that is within a json folder on wwwroot:

```
function GetBucklingData() {
   var returnData;
   $.ajax({
       url: "/json/BucklingData.json",
       async: false
   }).done(function (data) {
       returnData = JSON.parse(data);
   });

   return returnData;
}
```

Here is an example grep statement from within a function:

```
 var rods = $.grep(bucklingData, function (s) {
      return (s.Bore == boreValue);
 });
```

The statement is called like this:

```
var bucklingData = GetBucklingData();
PopulateBoreDropdown(bucklingData);
```

It seems that ajax isnt able to find the json file. The code is working outside of .net with a simple html page and a standalone folder so the json file appears to be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: this will fail because assignation of returnData in callback "done" occurs after `return returnData` instruction

Comment: [MDN - Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Comment: [Introduction to asynchronous javascript](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)

Comment: Can you show how grep is called ?

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: your function GetBucklingData will always return undefined (cf. previous answer). Once you fix this you still have to ensure your json is an array or an object with a length property

Answer (score 0):

instead of using your function like this:

```
function GetBucklingData() {
   var returnData;
   $.ajax({
       url: "/json/BucklingData.json",
       async: false
   }).done(function (data) {
       returnData = JSON.parse(data);
   });

   return returnData;
}

var data = GetBucklingData();
```

change to an async logic:

```
function GetBucklingData(callback) {
   var returnData;
   $.ajax({
       url: "/json/BucklingData.json",
       async: false
   }).done(function (data) {
       callback(JSON.parse(data));
   });
}


GetBucklingData(function(data) {
  // here you have your data
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately the error still persists after using your async logic method. Will update the question showing the specific error within jquery.